# How to use "Extended String Delimiters" in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, delimiter

I tried to print the extended string delimiter sample provided in the [swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) under the topic "Extended String Delimiters"

It throws the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use extented string delimiters, you have to use Swift 5 which is included in Xcode 10.2